Location tracking stops when app goes to background. Any solution?
Our flutter app is job portal app where user confirms odd jobs and agencies posts jobs in it. Now we want to add real-time location feature which will tracks the user live location 1 hour before the shift starts.
I'm trying different techniques. For app termination state, I have found the alarm package which schedules a notification to the app when it is killed and make the app again active by it.
Any suggestions with this? How can I track user location constantly when the app is in foregound and background?
Here's the code I'm using to test the feature on a sample app
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';

import 'package:location/location.dart' as l;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool gpsEnabled = false;
  bool permissionGranted = false;
  l.Location location = l.Location();
  late StreamSubscription subscription;
  bool trackingEnabled = false;

  List<l.LocationData> locations = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkStatus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stopTracking();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Location App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            buildListTile(
              "GPS",
              gpsEnabled
                  ? const Text("Okey")
                  : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    requestEnableGps();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Enable Gps")),
            ),
            buildListTile(
              "Permission",
              permissionGranted
                  ? const Text("Okey")
                  : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    requestLocationPermission();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Request Permission")),
            ),
            buildListTile(
              "Location",
              trackingEnabled
                  ? ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    stopTracking();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Stop"))
                  : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: gpsEnabled && permissionGranted
                      ? () {
                    startTracking();
                  }
                      : null,
                  child: const Text("Start")),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: clearFirestoreDatabase,
              child: const Text("Clear Firestore Database"),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: locations.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                          "${locations[index].latitude} ${locations[index].longitude}"),
                    );
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListTile buildListTile(
      String title,
      Widget? trailing,
      ) {
    return ListTile(
      dense: true,
      title: Text(title),
      trailing: trailing,
    );
  }

  void requestEnableGps() async {
    if (gpsEnabled) {
      log("Already open");
    } else {
      bool isGpsActive = await location.requestService();
      if (!isGpsActive) {
        setState(() {
          gpsEnabled = false;
        });
        log("User did not turn on GPS");
      } else {
        log("gave permission to the user and opened it");
        setState(() {
          gpsEnabled = true;
        });

      }
    }
  }

  void requestLocationPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus =
    await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      setState(() {
        permissionGranted = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        permissionGranted = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isPermissionGranted() async {
    return await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isGranted;
  }

  Future<bool> isGpsEnabled() async {
    return await Permission.location.serviceStatus.isEnabled;
  }

  checkStatus() async {
    bool _permissionGranted = await isPermissionGranted();
    bool _gpsEnabled = await isGpsEnabled();
    setState(() {
      permissionGranted = _permissionGranted;
      gpsEnabled = _gpsEnabled;
    });
  }

  addLocation(l.LocationData data) {
    setState(() {
      locations.insert(0, data);
    });
  }

  clearLocation() {
    setState(() {
      locations.clear();
    });
  }

  Future<void> addLocationToFirestore(l.LocationData locationData) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations').add({
        'latitude': locationData.latitude,
        'longitude': locationData.longitude,
      });
      log("Location added to Firestore: ${locationData.latitude}, ${locationData.longitude}");
    } catch (e) {
      log("Failed to add location: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> clearFirestoreDatabase() async {
    try {
      CollectionReference locations =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations');

      // Get all documents in the "locations" collection
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await locations.get();

      // Delete each document in the collection
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        await doc.reference.delete();
        log("Document with ID ${doc.id} deleted");
      }

      log("Firestore database cleared successfully.");
    } catch (e) {
      log("Failed to clear Firestore database: $e");
    }
  }

  void startTracking() async {
    if (!(await isGpsEnabled())) {
      return;
    }
    if (!(await isPermissionGranted())) {
      return;
    }
    subscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((event) {
      addLocation(event);
      addLocationToFirestore(event); // Save to Firestore
      log('Location update: ${event.latitude}, ${event.longitude}');
    });
    setState(() {
      trackingEnabled = true;
    });
  }



  void stopTracking() {
    subscription.cancel();
    setState(() {
      trackingEnabled = false;
    });
    clearLocation();
  }
}

The technique here discussed successfully gets and updates the user location coordinates(latitude, longitude) in the database when the app is in opened. But when the app puts to background, the location updates sending to database stops.

I think you should use the flutter_background_service package. This is the only package I used in my application. It works in the background using notifications. If your app is killed or in the background, it works fine.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service
